# SHELL automatically kill process from crontab

Tags: shell, centos7, kill, kill-process

I have several java processes but only those problematic I would like to  kill periodically on every 2 minutes on Centos7.

I would like to kill process PIDs which are run over this command.

```
/var/tmp/java -c /var/tmp/w.conf
```

If I try `kill` using the process ID process is killed automatically.

If I try to run this:

```
kill $(ps aux | grep 'java -c '| awk '{print $2}')
```

I am getting result:

```
-bash: kill: (129253) - No such process
```

how I should define script and crontab to kill automatically those processes?

Comment: Run the command and observe `ps aux | grep 'java -c '` output. You are trying to kill the `grep` command, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
pkill -f '/var/tmp/java -c /var/tmp/w.conf'
```

Answer (score 1):

In a terminal enter `crontab -e` to edit your crontab and then use the following command in the crontab editor (it works like `vi`).

```
*/2 * * * * pkill -f '/var/tmp/java -c /var/tmp/w.conf'
```

Don't forget to save via `:wq`. The above-mention command in crontab kills your desire app **every 2 Minutes**.